# Obj mesh does not render correctly

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, render

I have a problem with the rendering of a cube. I don't know why but it isn't correct.

Here are two images of the "cube":

Front:

[image: Front]

Back:

[image: Back]

Here's the OpenGL code:
Vertices, faces, colors..

```
private void initTriangle() {
    float[] coords = {
            -0.5f, 0.f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 1.f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, 1.f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, 1.f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, 1.f, -0.5f,
    };
    _nrOfVertices = coords.length;

    float[] colors = {
            1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, // point 1 red
            0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, // point 2 green
            0f, 0f, 1f, 1f, // point 3 blue
            1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, // point 4 white
            1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, // point 5 white
            1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, // point 6 white
            1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, // point 7 white
            1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, // point 8 white
            1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, // point 9 white
            1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, // point 10 white
            1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, // point 11 white
            1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, // point 12 white
    };

    short[] indices = new short[] {
            1, 2, 3, // 1
            3, 4, 1, // 2
            5, 6, 7, // 3
            7, 8, 5, // 4
            1, 4, 6, // 5
            6, 5, 1, // 6
            4, 3, 7, // 7
            7, 6, 4, // 8
            3, 2, 8, // 9
            8, 7, 3, // 10
            2, 1, 5, // 11
            5, 8, 2, // 12
    };

    // float has 4 bytes, coordinate * 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coords.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    _vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

    // short has 2 bytes, indices * 2 bytes
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    _indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();

    // float has 4 bytes, colors (RGBA) * 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
    cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    _colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();

    _vertexBuffer.put(coords);
    _indexBuffer.put(indices);
    _colorBuffer.put(colors);

    _vertexBuffer.position(0);
    _indexBuffer.position(0);
    _colorBuffer.position(0);
}
```

Rendering:
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);

```
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set rotation
    gl.glRotatef(_xAngle, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef(_yAngle, 0f, 1f, 0f);


    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _colorBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _nrOfVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
}
```

here the obj content:

```
# 3ds Max Wavefront OBJ Exporter v0.97b - (c)2007 guruware
# File Created: 19.02.2012 13:31:12

mtllib box22.mtl

#
# object Box01
#

v  -0.5000 0.0000 0.5000
v  -0.5000 0.0000 -0.5000
v  0.5000 0.0000 -0.5000
v  0.5000 0.0000 0.5000
v  -0.5000 1.0000 0.5000
v  0.5000 1.0000 0.5000
v  0.5000 1.0000 -0.5000
v  -0.5000 1.0000 -0.5000
# 8 vertices

vn 0.0000 -1.0000 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 -0.0000
# 6 vertex normals

vt 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vt 1.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vt 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vt 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
# 4 texture coords

g Box01
usemtl wire_177088026
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 
f 3/3/1 4/4/1 1/1/1 
f 5/4/2 6/1/2 7/2/2 
f 7/2/2 8/3/2 5/4/2 
f 1/4/3 4/1/3 6/2/3 
f 6/2/3 5/3/3 1/4/3 
f 4/4/4 3/1/4 7/2/4 
f 7/2/4 6/3/4 4/4/4 
f 3/4/5 2/1/5 8/2/5 
f 8/2/5 7/3/5 3/4/5 
f 2/4/6 1/1/6 5/2/6 
f 5/2/6 8/3/6 2/4/6 
# 12 faces
```

Hope you can help me.

Thank for your attention (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your indices are correct.

The OBJ format starts counting with indices at 1. However, the actual indexing within your array will start at 0. So you will have to subtract 1 from each index within the OBJ file for it to work as you expect.